# Show that ODE doesn’t have a solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was given an ODE: $$x y'+3y+y^2=x^2$$
We can rewrite this as: $$y'=\frac{-1}{x}y^2-\frac{3}{x}y+x$$
which is obviously a Riccati equation so to solve it we need to find a particular solution for $y$, let's denote it as $y_p$. Once we find that particular solution we can make a substitution $\displaystyle y=y_p+\frac{1}{z}$, where $z=z(x)$.
The problem is I couldn't come up with any $y_p$ that would satisfy the given equation. So I decided to calculate it using Mathematica and I got, what looks like a complex function.

Since $y$ has to be a real valued function, it seems that there are no solutions to our ODE. How can we conclude that just from the given ODE? Is there something simple I'm missing here?

**Edit**
Since it was requested in the comments, here is the solution I got from Mathematica:
$y(x)=-\frac{i x \left(-\frac{2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \left(-\frac{3 \cosh (x)}{x^2}+\frac{3 \sinh (x)}{x}-\cosh (x)\right)}{\sqrt{i x}}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} c_1 \left(-\frac{3 i \sinh (x)}{x^2}-i \sinh (x)+\frac{3 i \cosh (x)}{x}\right)}{\sqrt{i x}}-\frac{i \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} c_1 \sinh (x)}{\sqrt{i x}}\right)+\frac{3 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} c_1 \left(\frac{\sinh (x)}{x}-\cosh (x)\right)}{\sqrt{i x}}}{2 \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \left(\frac{i \cosh (x)}{x}-i \sinh (x)\right)}{\sqrt{i x}}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} c_1 \left(\frac{\sinh (x)}{x}-\cosh (x)\right)}{\sqrt{i x}}\right)}$

Comment: Please edit your question to include the solution.

Comment: @Gonçalo it doesn't add anything to the question, but there you go.

Comment: On the contrary, it adds a lot! Wait for my answer.

Comment: If $x=0$ then $y$ must be either $0$ or $-3$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other approach to Riccati equations introduces a degree of freedom by setting $y=u/v$ to get
$$
x(u'v-uv')+3uv+u^2=x^2v^2.
$$
Now one can group terms with a factor of $u$ and those with a factor of $v$. There is some choice in distributing the mixed term
$$
(xu'+au-x^2v)v=u(xv'+(a-3)v-u)
$$
The degree of freedom that was introduced is used up in setting both sides to zero. For $a=0$ this gives
$$
u'=xv\\
xv'=u+3v
$$
and combined
$$
xv''=xv+2v'
$$
The WA solution suggests the parametrization $v=xz'-z=x^2(z/x)'$, $v'=xz''$. Inserted this gives
$$
x^2z'''+xz''=2xz''+x^2z'-xz\\
(xD-1)(D^2-1)z=0\\
z''-z=w\\
xw'-w=0
$$
Solving backwards this gives $w=Cx$, $z=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+Cx$,
$$
v=A(x-1)e^x-B(x+1)e^{-x},\\
u=xv'-3v=x^2z''-3xz'+3z
\\=A(x^2-3x+3)e^x+B(x^2+3x+3)e^{-x}.
\\~\\
y=\frac{A(x^2-3x+3)e^x+B(x^2+3x+3)e^{-x}}{A(x-1)e^x-B(x+1)e^{-x}}
$$
This can also be expressed in hyperbolic functions

Comment: +1 Nice. ${}{}$

Answer (score 2):

The solution given by Mathematica can be simplified by canceling the common factor $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ix}}$ in the numerator and in the denominator. It can then be rewritten as
$$
y(x)=\frac{if(x)+c_1g(x)}{iu(x)+c_1v(x)}, \tag{1}
$$
where $f(x),g(x),u(x),$ and $v(x)$ are real functions. Taking $c_1=iC$, where $C$ is real, one ends with a real solution
$$
y(x)=\frac{f(x)+Cg(x)}{u(x)+Cv(x)}. \tag{2}
$$

Comment: This is what you should get after simplyfing: $$\frac{i \left(x^2+3 i c_1 x+3\right) \cosh (x)+\left(c_1 \left(x^2+3\right)-3 i x\right) \sinh (x)}{(c_1 x-i) \cosh (x)+i (x+i c_1) \sinh (x)}$$. This doesn't look like your form of $y(x)$. But even if it did and your solution was correct it doesn't help me much, because this is the first problem (which usually means it should be trivial) in a textbook that doesn't go into complex functions.

Comment: The expression you obtained can be rewritten as $$\frac{i[(x^2+3)\cosh(x)-3x\sinh(x)]+c_1[-3x\cosh(x)+(x^3+3)\sinh(x)]}{i[-\cosh(x)+x\sinh(x)]+c_1[x\cosh(x)-\sinh(x)]},$$which has the form of Eq. $(1)$. And my point is that there is nothing wrong with the ODE, but with the way Mathematica presents its solution, which is not explicitly real. (However, it can be made explicitly real with a suitable redefinition of $c_1$.)